# @gen.coroutine not defined in python with tornado

Tags: python, generator, tornado

I am developing a web and am using tornado server with motor. I use the generator to find the document from the collection. When the code is executed I get an error saying @gen is not defined. Motor, `tornado.ioloop` and `tornado.web` has been imported.

```
@gen.coroutine
def do_find_one():
    document = yield db.users.find_one()
    print (document)
```

One more thing is the web server could not be closed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I have to close the terminal every time and then start from beginning. Is there a way to stop the service in the terminal itself.

Comment: I have just started learning python, so please even if my question seems lame to you please answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should also import `gen` to use it:

```
from tornado import gen
```

Python names are very straghtforward. You should either define a variable in your module or import it explicitly (or implicitly with `from foo import *` while it's not a recommended way).

Comment: thank you very much. I was doing this wrong all the time like `import gen` instead of `from tornado import gen`